# How do I store all results from a function into a single variable in Lua?

Tags: arrays, function, lua

I have

```
function foo()
    return a, b
end
x, y = foo() -- x == a, y == b
z = foo() -- z == a
```

Is there a simpler way to transfer both `a` and `b` (and any more variable in the function) into `z` as an array?

initializing `z` with `z = {}` didn't work because it just redefines it as the first result of `foo()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

```
-- define the function
function foo()
    return "one", "two"
end
-- set z to a table of the return values of foo().  The first return
-- value will be z[1], the second one z[2], and so on.
z = {foo()}
-- print it out
for k,v in pairs(z) do
    print(k, v)
end
```

Should get

```
1   one
2   two
```

Is that the sort of thing you're looking for?

Comment: I don't know what `pairs` does, but I don't need to. I handle `z` differently. This works. Thank you.

Comment: You're very welcome.  And you're gonna love pairs() someday soon (it's super handy).